# Наследование в С++

Tags: наследование, c++

Есть вот такой вот код (пример):

```
class A{
     public:
         A(int x,int y){//конструктор с параметрами
             //nothing...
         }
 };

class B:public virtual A{
    public:
        B(int x,int y,int z):A(x,y){//констрктор, в котором вызываются конструктор родитля, все логчно
            //nothing...
        }
};

class C:public virtual B{
    public:
        C(int x,int y,int z,int value):B(x,y,z),A(x,y){//вот только так работает
            //nothing...
        }

};
```

Почему в классе С приходится писать вызов коструктор A. Почему он не может вызваться из класса B?

Есть какое-то подозрение, будто это связано с **виртуальным наследованием**. Но хочу узнать наверняка.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы правильно догадываетесь - это связано именно с виртуальным наследованием, т.к. в этом случае инициализация виртуального базового класса происходит в самом дальнем по иерархии потомке, в вашем случае в классе `C`.

В этом-то и есть смысл виртуальных базовых классов - они присутствуют в объекте производного класса только в одном экземпляре. Активно используется при множественном наследовании от классов, имеющих общий базовый класс. В вашем случае это, скорее всего, лишнее.